# Using regex's to relabel and remove redundent items in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to use pythons regex features to relabel some identifiers in some text.

Here is an example of the text. I am essentially trying to number all the v's in numerical order.

```
@r=v4 "v4"
 A -> C : B
 Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A) 
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> : D 
 Cell * kcat2 * D * C / (km2 + C)
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
```

So the desired output would be

```
@r=v1 "v1"
 A -> C : B
 Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A) 
@r=v2 "v2"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
@r=v3 "v3"
 C -> : D 
 Cell * kcat2 * D * C / (km2 + C)
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
```

However there is also a complication. If you look carefully you can see that the 'v2' and 'v4' elements are identical. This is therefore redundant information for me and needs to me removed.

My Code:

```
string='''
@r=v4 "v4"
 A -> C : B
 Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A) 
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> : D 
 Cell * kcat2 * D * C / (km2 + C)
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
'''

pattern=re.compile('@r=(.*)')
    for i in range(len(re.findall(pattern,string))):
        print re.sub(pattern,'@r=v{} "v{}"'.format(str(i+1),str(i+1)),string)
```

This however does not give me the desired output. Does anybody know how to do what I want? Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with regular expressions?

Comment: Hi Jon, do you have a better alternative?

Comment: It seems like just iterating over the lines would be easier, for a start.

Comment: The string that I have shown has already been processed and concatenated from two files. So now, if I iterate over the string I get individual characters not the whole line

Comment: *Ahem*: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probable solution:

```
string='''@r=v4 "v4"
 A -> C : B
 Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A) 
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> : D 
 Cell * kcat2 * D * C / (km2 + C)
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C'''

i = 0
for strg in string.splitlines():
    if strg == '@r=v4 "v4"':
        i += 1
        print '@r=v{} "v{}"'.format(i,i)
    else:
        print strg
```

Output:

```
@r=v1 "v1"
 A -> C : B
 Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A) 
@r=v2 "v2"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
@r=v3 "v3"
 C -> : D 
 Cell * kcat2 * D * C / (km2 + C)
@r=v4 "v4"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
```

You can easily *concat* all string and get text with relabeled identifiers. Like this:

```
new_text = ""
for strg in string.splitlines():
    if strg == '@r=v4 "v4"':
        i += 1
        new_text += '@r=v{} "v{}"\n'.format(i,i)
    else:
        new_text += strg + '\n'
```

For just little bit more difficult case:

```
for strg in string.splitlines():
if strg in ['@r=v4 "v4"','@r=v2 "v2"','@r=v3 "v3"'] : # any string if there aren't huge amount of cases
    i += 1
    print '@r=v{} "v{}"'.format(i,i)
else:
    print strg
```

Comment: Hi Gregg, Thank you so much for answering. This is precisely what I want except I need the code to be generalizable to any piece of text of this format. I.e. sometimes the first row will be v3 and the second v2. This is why I was using regex's

Comment: You're welcome! If I clearly understand you it's possible just to add checks for cases of "v3" and "v2" in _"if else"_ statement, aren't it?

Comment: @user3059024, I've added some code, is it what you need?